# Java - Read package and Class name from file

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to read package and class name from file. In the below code fileEntry.getName() is giving me output *C:User\mywork\Myproject\target\generated-source\java\demo\Project.java*. I want to get only **demo.Project** as an output. Appreciate suggestion thank you

```
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            //C:User\mywork\Myproject\target\generated-source\java\demo\Project.java

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the path before "demo" fix or variable? Is the package name the same as the package name of the class you are running the code?

Comment: @Jens it is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you only need to find java class files and you want inner packages declared as `package1.package2.demo.Project`. You can do some String manipulation to get that output.

```
public static String FILE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator");

public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            if (!fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
                continue;
            }
            String absolutePath = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
            String javaPackageSeparator = FILE_SEPARATOR + "java" + FILE_SEPARATOR;
            int indexOf = absolutePath.indexOf(javaPackageSeparator);
            if (indexOf > -1) {
                String javaFilePath = absolutePath.substring(indexOf, absolutePath.length());
                String strippedJavaSeparator = javaFilePath.replace(javaPackageSeparator, "");
                String[] constructProperPackageName = strippedJavaSeparator.split(Pattern.quote(FILE_SEPARATOR));
                String packageName = "";
                String className = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < constructProperPackageName.length; i++) {
                    if (i == constructProperPackageName.length - 1) {
                        className = constructProperPackageName[i].replace(".java", "");
                        continue;
                    }
                    packageName += constructProperPackageName[i] + ".";
                }
                System.out.println(packageName + className);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces output as following:

```
com.company.exception.handler.AbstractExceptionHandler
com.company.exception.handler.IExceptionHandler
com.company.exception.handler.APIRequestExceptionHandler
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Haris this is what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple scan across the root / source directory using `Files.find` will return all java files, and then you can adjust the path to generate package name.

```
Path srcDir = Path.of("src");
BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> dotjava = (p,a) -> a.isRegularFile() && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".java");
try(var java = Files.find(srcDir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, dotjava)) {
    java.map(p -> srcDir.relativize(p).toString().replaceAll("\\.java$", "").replace(File.separator, "."))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```